# Bash PS1 dissappears after history browsing

Tags: bash, ps1

I have been configuring my new fresh Arch installation. I just finished with my `PS1` in Bash and realized about an error I do not know how to solve.

This is the code:

```sh
PS1='\n\[\e[30;44m \u@\h \]\[\e[34;45m\]\[\e[30;45m \w \]\[\e[35;46m\]\[\e[30;46m $(__git_ps1 "(%s)") \]\[\e[0;36m\]\[\e[0m\]\n\[\e[0;42m \# \]\[\e[32;41m\]\[\e[0;41m \$ \]\[\e[0;31m\]\[\e[0m\] '
```

And I get this:

[image: My PS1 config (visual)]

Then I continued with my config time and realized that if I use any of the upwards arrow key or downwards arrow key (to browse through history) twice, I get this:

[image: My PS1 error (visual)]

Also this happens when doing recursive search:

[image: My PS1 error 2 (visual)]

Answer (score 0):

As said by @KamilMaciorowski I just had to take the displayed content out of `\[` and `\]`, so now my PS1 looks like this:

```sh
PS1='\n\[\e[30;44m\] \u@\h \[\e[34;45m\]\[\e[30;45m\] \w \[\e[35;46m\]\[\e[30;46m\] $(__git_ps1 "(%s)") \[\e[0;36m\]\[\e[0m\]\n\[\e[0;42m\] \# \[\e[32;41m\]\[\e[0;41m\] \$ \[\e[0;31m\]\[\e[0m\] '
```